# Is there anyway to check SMS filter extension enabled in containing app?

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios11

I am developing a **SMS filter extension** for iOS 11. For containing app, it seems there is no method to check if my SMS filter extension enabled on user's device. I didn't find any related method in `IdentityLookup` Framework.
Is there other way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API for this currently in iOS 11 Beta.

If this is a capability you would like to see I encourage you to file an official bug report requesting the capability using [Apple Bug Reporter (Radar)](http://bugreport.apple.com).